# Array in parent component cannot be assigned from a child component in angular2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular

There may be a simple explanation to this, so please excuse my ignorance.

When working with an array from the child component and using `.pop()`, `.splice()`, `.push()` on the passed value it persists the parent array value just fine, but when I try to assign value(`=`) it does not persist the array in the parent component.

I created a [simple example on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/azVGXcI6nN75nJCZfHp6?p=preview).

The program has 3 buttons, clear, pop, and reload.

**Clear list** - assigns the `@Input list` to an empty array (`this.list = []`). Notice that the parent component counter doesn't change

**Pop** - performs a `.pop()` on the list. Notice that the parent component counter changes.

How come I can't just simply assign the array value?

> I know can use an `EventEmitter` and have the parent listen for
>   the event and update it that way. Im trying to understand this
>   scenario and seeing if I can avoid the extra code.

Comment: say `list` points to memory `0x123`. `pop` method changes array on memory address `0x123`, hence, change are reflected both, in parent and in child. clear method assigns child components `list` property to `0x321`, parent component's `list` property points to `0x123`, on that memory address no change happened.

Comment: Solution. `this.list.length = 0;` However, you should understand that having two widgets manipulate the same data is going to make your logic hard to follow. That's why there are frameworks like redux so data can flow one way, and updates in the other way happen in a consistent, debuggable way. An in the middle approach is to emit and event from the child widget and have the parent widget respond to that event and update the list

Comment: awesome thanks for the explanations fellas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent and child both have a reference to the same/one array object.  So if you change elements of the array (e.g., modify an array element, or add or remove elements), both parent and child "see" the changes because the changes are happening to that same/one object.

If you assign a new array in the parent, Angular change detection will propagate the new array reference down to the child, since this is an input property on the child.

However, if you assign a new array in the child, the parent will still have a reference to the original array.  Angular change detection won't help you here. You would have to inform the parent about this new array, e.g., using an EventEmitter.